# Run-Time Error 76: Path Not Found

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the basic code below to copy files from one location to another.

```
Sub CopyFilesToLocation()

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 69 To lRow

    FileCopy Cells(i, 19), "C:\Users\a222012\Desktop\Test\" & Cells(i, 9) & ".pdf"

Next i

End Sub
```

Cell (i,19) contains a hyperlink to a pdf file. I have about 5000 files. Using `On Error Resume Next` helped me get passed the run-time error and extract about 4400 files. The remaining 600 will all give the run-time error without `On Error Resume Next`. The 600 files have valid links, as when clicked, the pdf opens. Any idea why I would be getting the error?

Edit: All files are on a network drive. Example of path:
`\\19549dabjnb0002\images\2017.07\11\A217081\20170711095405.pdf`

Comment: Can we see the link that works when clicked

Comment: Hi, edited post to include example of link

Comment: I think your problem is that you have like 3 \\\ when their should only be 1. Is the path you posted in cell 9 or 19

Comment: Yep the \ was the issue. I commented in the answer below. Thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileCopy works quite good](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y(v=vs.90).aspx).  Try to simplify your code to something small, then start working from there. And remove `On Error Resume Next`. Something like this should work:

```
Sub CopyFilesToLocation()

    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\" & Cells(2, 1)
    Debug.Print Cells(1, 1)
    Debug.Print strPath

    Stop 'Take a look at the immediate window
    FileCopy Cells(1, 1), strPath

End Sub
```

When the code stops, take a look at the immediate window `Ctrl+G`.

**Edit:**
For the optimized moving, simply use the two paths and add the file to them separately. It will loop easily:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strPathD As String 'Destination path
    Dim strPathL As String 'Location path

    strPathL = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\"
    strPathD = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\NewFolder\"

    FileCopy strPathL & Cells(1, 1), strPathD & Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This helped me find the error. The cell I was using to name the file contained a \ and as result it was adding that to the destination path which obviously doesn't exist! Thanks man!

Comment: Any idea on how I copy the file with its current name instead of naming it using a cell value?

Comment: @KoderM16 - simply give the path and the destination separately, then it should be easy. Will edit soon.